# How to use SQL Server Change tracking to Increase Reports performance?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports, change-tracking

I have some reports developed by ASP.NET MVC with crystal reports based on SQL Server queries. These queries take very long time for execution because there are very heavy calculations and the result should be real time.

I think if I saved the result of calculations in a new table so reports can read these results directly. I thought if I used SQL Server change tracking for determine changes to update the new table.

The problem is how can automatically update the new table using SQL Server Change tracking?

Comment: Cant you do the calculations in reports insstead of the queries

Comment: CT has nothing to do with it in this scenario. Write your own triggers/sps to maintain and refresh your aggregated denormalized data serially or immediately on each data change. Or review your report code and make it more efficient. Build some indexes for it.

Comment: You might also want to look into indexed views. You might not be able to put complex calculations there, but you might be able to reduce the number of rows.